# Difference between $p\cos θ$ and $\cos pθ$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry

Is "$\cos pθ$" different from "$p\cosθ$"  ? What is the reason?

Comment: The cosine is *not* a linear function. If it were, considering $\theta=0$, the cosine could take any real value.

Comment: Kindly elaborate.

Comment: $\cos$ lies between $-1$ and $1$, it loses this constraint if you scale it by $p$ (i.e. $p$ outside).

Comment: Is what I've added clear enough? . Furthermore, the graph of a linear function is a straight line.

Comment: Look, I don't know what you are saying. I'm a high school student. My confusion is that if we multiply p with cosθ.. would it make any difference whether we write pcosθ or cospθ as a product?

Comment: @flappybird;: Yes, it would make a difference since we have in trigonometry the *duplication formulæ*: $\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$.

Comment: @Bernard Yup, if we I look from that perspective, I understand. I was just wondering about it using obvious multiplication rules.

Comment: B.t.w., in high school, aren't you supposed to know what a linear function is?

Comment: @Bernard I knew many things, about function, but my bad, I did not know about their "linearity"

Comment: A linear function (of a single variable) is simply $x\longmapsto cx$ for some coefficient $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $\cos$ with $f$ and then $f$ with $sq$ where $sq(x)=x^2$. $sq(2x)=4sq(x)$ and that is no big surprise.

A class of functions satisfying your property of $p\cdot f(x) = f(px)$ is a very special and important class of functions. They're called linear :)

Comment: And cosine is not linear so it does'not follow this pattern?

Comment: @ProThala how do we know if a function is linear or not?

Comment: @flappybird Have you studied about linear equations? Basically a linear function is one whose graph is a straight line. Graph of cosine function is like waves and its not a linear function.

Comment: Most precisely. Cosine isn't linear as it doesn't follow this pattern.
A linear function will, if nothing else, has a plot in form of a straight line, cosine doesn't resemble a straight line in the slightest, unless you're looking too closely :)

Comment: @ProThala So non-linear functions do not hold commutative property of multiplication?

Comment: The pointwise multiplication of real-valued functions is indeed commutative. But $p*f(x)$ has nothing to do with commutativity unless you consider $(f(x))*p$ in comparison

Comment: Just keep in mind that $\cos \phi$ is a shorthand for $(\cos(\phi))$, and the inner parentheses are the function evaluation operation

Comment: Oh, oh, oh, cos(θ) "θ" is input and we cannot just add p in it and expect it to behave like multiplication. I get it. If p would slide and stand along θ, like cos(pθ) it would be wrong. Cuz p would actually be become a part of the input.

Comment: @Thehx oh, conventionally, it is not used, and that caused me confusion

Comment: rule of thumb, if the argument of a function is anything syntactically more complicated than $px$, i.e. $\cos px$, just write parentheses. It never hurts.

Comment: @Thehx yup, not only shoud I do it, the whole world should do it, so future generations can easily understand. :)

Comment: the whole world treats $\cos^2 x$ as $(\cos(x))^2$, and $\cos^{-1} x$ as $\arccos(x)$ at the same time (instead of $\frac{1}{\cos x}$), so I don't think there's salvation to it :)

Answer (score 0):

$\cos\phi$ is a shorthand for $(\cos(\phi))$, and the inner parentheses are the function evaluation operation. In $\cos(\theta)$ "$\theta$" is input and we cannot just add $p$ in it and expect it to behave like multiplication. If "$p$" would slide and stand along $θ$, like $\cos(p\theta)$ it would be wrong because $p$ would actually become a part of the input.